# CPU Memory type and memory bus frequency

Tags: memory, cpu

I am reading about computer components to collect for a gaming computer. So far I am thinking of:

- [ASUS Z170-PRO](https://www.asus.com/uk/Motherboards/Z170-PRO/specifications/)
- [Intel® Core™ i7-7700K](http://ark.intel.com/products/97129/Intel-Core-i7-7700K-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-4_50-GHz?_ga=1.246593284.1695556565.1484598231), and
- [Corsair Red Vengeance LPX 32GB 3000MHz DDR4](https://www.scan.co.uk/products/32gb-(2x16gb)-corsair-ddr4-vengeance-lpx-red-pc3-24000-(3000)-non-ecc-unbuffered-cas-15-17-17-35-xmp)

My question is about memory and CPU. It says in Intel's specifications that the processor I am thinking of can run DDR4 memory at max 2400 Mhz freq bus. ASUS Z170 PRO motherboard can operate at much higher frequency bus, much over 3000 MHz. What does it mean? Do I need to be strict and buy memory with 2400 Mhz or will I benefit anything if I buy memory kit with more than 2400 MHz ?

Thanks

Comment: May I ask why it was down voted? I did ask specific question. didn't I?

Comment: Instead of spending time asking the reason somebody issued a vote and didn't leave feedback.  Go through your question (again) and find ways to improve it.  There is always something you do to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

You will almost always benefit from using memory with a higher maximum frequency than your hardware can support. When a memory module runs at a lower frequency than its maximum, it improves its clock timings and reduces latency.